# Problems in connect signal/slot, qRegisterMetaType() QList<QString>

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I have a working thread that collects data and shows them on a widget. I tried to put those data in QList list. It first give me error that i need to register MetaType, but after I did that it gives me new error that it's not registered in this scope.

There is a lot of code, so I'll give a short version

widget.h in public part has MyThread *thread;

widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    thread = new MyThread(this);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(ShowData(QList<QString>)), this, SLOT(ev_ShowData(QList<QString>)));

    thread.start();
}
```

thread.cpp

```
MyThread::run()
{
   class.GetData();
   emit ShowData(class.list);
}
```

}

class.h:

```
#include<QMetaType>

class UNTITLEDSHARED_EXPORT iMag
{

  public:
  Class();

  typedef QList<QString> MyList;
  void GetData();

};
```

class.cpp:

```
#include class.h

Class::Class()
{
   qRegisterMetaType<MyList>("MyList");
}

Class::GetData()
{
  // A lot of code and then a error part

  MyList.clear();
  MyList << stringToBeWriten;

  // it gives me error in these two lines of cdoe
}
```

Also I'm new in Qt so I'm sure it's a simple solution, but I cant figure it out...

Comment: the biggest mistake made by Qt newbies and anyone using Qt is not knowing the wonderful classes and mechanisms already available and fully documented.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, then your syntax is wrong in this line: `qRegisterMetaType<list> list;`.

It should be something like:

```
qRegisterMetaType<list>("list");
```

See the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

You also seem to be trying to use a type as a variable here:

```
list.clear();
list << stringToBeWriten;
```

What you should do is declare a variable with that type. You can do this in your `class.h`:

```
list myList;
```

Then you can use it like:

```
myList.clear();
myList << stringToBeWriten;
```

Comment: My code is actually like you said, I edited ti now, it was just typing error. Non of that is my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the hassle and use [QStringList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html). 
 For the record your issue come from the fact that Qt preprocessor for signals and slots, the moc, does not use a full-blown C++ parser.It will look for the signature of methods using ***string matching***. Thus the following will fail

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(ShowData(QList<QString>)), this, SLOT(ev_ShowData(QList<QString>)));
```

Because you have registered `"MyList"`, which as a string, doesn't match "`QList<QString>"`.

With templates I think the best bet is to use specialization via sub-classing (hence not a template anymore). It is to be able to make

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(ShowData(MyList)), this, SLOT(ev_ShowData(MyList)));
```

note: I see you are subclassing QThread. [It is likely you dont need to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qthread/info)

Comment: "Qt is very bad at dealing with templates" This is really confusing the matter. All that Qt needs is that a type used in signals/slots is always named the same. The underlying reason is simple: the implementation - parsing of `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros, the `moc` tool, etc. - does not use a full-blown C++ parser. Qt's semantics of types is that of strings. If the strings differ, the types don't match. It's that simple. You're free to use namespaces and templates as long as they are all the same everywhere *as strings*.

Comment: With the realization that Qt needs runtime parsing of types comes the inevitable outcome: if you want Qt not to be "vary bad" at this, you'd need to bundle llvm's clang with every Qt application. Then, frankly said, instead of complaints about "being bad at templates", we'd hear complaints about "Qt is teh bloatz". You can't have your cake and eat it too, you know.

Comment: Ok I need to rephrase that. I am not hating on one of the best c++ libraries out there. Can I borrow something from your comment?

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't declare << operator for `MyList` type
2. You forgot to call `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators`

I propose you next helper for such issues:

```
template < typename T >
class MetaTypeRegistration
{
public:
    inline MetaTypeRegistration()
    {
        qRegisterMetaType< T >();
        qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators< T >();
    }
};
```

But in your case it's prefferable to use `QStringList` :)